# Powerapps UpdateIf with multiple conditions

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am trying to use an UpdateIf function in Powerapps to update a record in Sharepoint based on two conditions. However, the second condition seems to be ignored. The function is as below:

```
UpdateIf('Demo Stock';(PartNumber = ThisItem.Code && Serial = ThisItem.Serial);{ItemStatus: "Available"})
```

The update happens but there are multiple instances where ParNumber value is the same in the SharePoint List and all instances are being updated insted of only the one where bothe PartNumber and SerialNumber match.

Any ideas why?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get this figured out? I'm guessing your issue is the extra ';' you've got in the statement.

Try the following:
UpdateIf('Demo Stock',PartNumber = ThisItem.Code && Serial = ThisItem.Serial,{ItemStatus: "Available"})

I hope that helps! Meanwhile, your question answered mine on how to achieve AND for two conditions (&&). :-)

Lucinda

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UpdateIf('Demo Stock';And(PartNumber = ThisItem.Code; Serial = ThisItem.Serial);{ItemStatus: "Available"})
```